# How to get past Welcome (language) screen when automating install?

Tags: system-installation, pxe, preseed, ubiquity

I have a working PXE boot, and can successfully install the 16.04 Desktop via PXE and NFS.

Now I'm trying to automate the PXE install, and I can't get past the installation's "Welcome" screen that asks for my language.

I've read through:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbiquityAutomation
and
https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/installation-guide/amd64/apbs01.html

This is my pxe boot command:

```
LABEL Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit -- PRESEED
        KERNEL Ubuntu/16.04/amd64/vmlinuz.efi
        APPEND automatic-ubiquity file=/srv/install/ubuntu/16.04/amd64/preseed/custom.seed boot=boot=casper netboot=nfs nfsroot=myip:/srv/install/ubuntu/16.04/amd64 initrd=Ubuntu/16.04/am64/initrd.lz
```

And here is the top of custom.seed

```
ubiquity languagechooser/language-name select English
ubiquity localechooser/supported-locales multiselect en_US.UTF8
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_GB.utf8
```

But these does seem to be enough to get past the installer's first question.

How can I get past the first Welcome/language screen?

EDIT:
I am using the CD Desktop Image that loads with a UI where you click the CD cion to install, not the netboot image.

Comment: I think most of these docs are for a server installation, not the desktop one with a GUI?

Comment: I think one of your issues is the kernel parameter line: "boot=boot=casper" should be boot=casper.

Answer (score 0):

The trick ends up being to modify the kernel boot commandline in your PXE entry (or e.g. in a grub.cfg or txt.cfg file or similar), adding `debian-installer/language=en`.

For example, my netboot setup's grub.cfg has this entry:

```
menuentry "Desktop 20.04 Installer" {
   set gfxpayload=keep
   linux ubuntu2004/vmlinuz ip=dhcp nfsroot=192.168.0.1:/netboot/nfs/ubuntu2004 netboot=nfs ro file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper systemd.mask=tmp.mount automatic-ubiquity fsck.mode=skip noprompt keyboard-configuration/layoutcode=us debian-installer/language=en --
   initrd ubuntu2004/initrd
}
```

(This may work in *combination* with entries in the preseed file. I did not test removing those after adding the above...)

---

How I came upon this:

- I've successfully preseeded everything else with my own installs, so had non-zero knowledge/experience here...
- Like you, I had `ubiquity languagechooser/language-name select English (US)` in my preseed file.  Not tested, but I suspect that changing this would change which language was initially selected in the GUI...
- Referencing https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/s390x/apbs02.html#preseed-auto, which talks about kernel command parameters (though doesn't give any examples that aren't preseed snippets): I had previously been using a `keyboard-configuration/layoutcode=us` parameter, and that page suggests several parameters, including `debian-installer/language=en`.
- From past installs, looking in `/var/log/installer/syslog` on an imaged system, I found that parameter mentioned:

```
Oct 16 00:37:33 ubuntu localechooser: info: debian-installer/language preseeded to 'en' (seen: false)
Oct 16 00:37:33 ubuntu localechooser: info: debian-installer/country preseeded to 'US' (seen: true)
Oct 16 00:37:33 ubuntu localechooser: info: debian-installer/locale preseeded to 'en_US.UTF-8' (seen: true)
```

- Note how the other two parameters have `seen: true`... this gave me confidence to try the parameter out.
- While the lines look like that still *after* adding the kernel commandline parameter, after adding `debian-installer/language=en`, things auto-ran and the parameter is now marked as "seen" earlier in this initial syslog.